# Text mode not working properly. Plus other problems

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, amd-processor

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 multiple times, always ending with some sort of bug that renders my system useless. So I have a few questions to ask.

When I boot, a purple selection screen comes up and gives me options (Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Memory test (memtest86+), Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200), Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)).
On earlier occasions I have not seen this.

Secondly, After booting I need to install my graphics drivers (Nvidia 343.22) but I cant do that without switching to text mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1). When I try to switch I am only greeted with a black screen but can still switch back to the desktop(Ctrl + Alt + F7). I don't know why it does this but it is really aggravating.

On a previous occasion I had got the drivers installed and it worked perfectly. I tried to install wine1.7 and after a reboot I was stuck at the loading screen (going nowhere).

I really just want my system back to the way it was but I am starting to give up hope.

Specs:

CPU:  AMD FX 8320

GPU:  Galax Nvidia GTX 970 EOC version

MOBO: Asrock Pro3 R2.0

RAM:  16GB Gskill Ripjaws X

Currently running two monitors.

Also have a secondary hard drive I pulled out of my old computer that has Windows 7 boot files.

Any help is appreciated.  (Please tell me if I am doing something stupidly idiotic.)